# fade in of added component with Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, effects, fade

Hi when I add a new component using Actionscript I want it to fade in smoothly, for example this component

```
    var df : DateField = new DateField();   
    df.text = DateField.dateToString(new Date(),stringFormat);
    df.formatString = stringFormat;
```

I tried this

```
    var fade : Fade = new Fade();
    df.setStyle("showEffect", fade);
```

but that did not work.

any ideas? =)

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The showEffect is only triggered when you change the .visible property of the component - you need to trigger that somewhere to experience the awesomeness of the fade.

I threw this together real quick so you can see what I mean (also notice I used a string to define the fade rather than an object - it always seems easier that way...hope it helps!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
                layout="absolute" 
                creationComplete="init()">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.controls.DateField;

            private function init():void{

                var df:DateField = new DateField();
                df.visible = false;
                df.setStyle("showEffect","Fade");
                this.addChild(df);
                df.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE,triggerFade);

            }

            private function triggerFade(event:FlexEvent):void{

                var df:DateField = event.currentTarget as DateField;    
                df.visible = true;

            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be pointed out that Adobe's tweening libraries and the sort are very slow. I would suggest GTween (still in beta, but I have not had any issues), TweenLite/Max (may have some licensing issues), or Tweener (Easy to use, but much slower than the other two), setting the alpha to 0 and then fading in to 1.
     It's not as easy, but these libraries provide much better performance.